# What is the meaning of 0 and 1 at the end of hyperkube image tag

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, hyperkube

Here https://quay.io/repository/coreos/hyperkube?tab=tags you can see that
there are two tags for 1.6.6:

- v1.6.6_coreos.0
- v1.6.6_coreos.1

What is the meaning of 0 and 1?
What is the difference between the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/coreos/kubernetes/releases , these are identical images, but one was re-tagged to allow new hyperkube image build at quay.io . For details, please have a look into provided link.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting :)